# Need nginx regex rewrite debuging help

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need custom Nginx regex](https://serverfault.com/questions/410522/need-custom-nginx-regex)

Desired outcome is this:

```
http://www.example.com/about/?r=something
```

to this:

```
http://www.example.com/about.php/?r=something
```

This is what I got but it isn't working:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/([^?]*[^?/])/?(\?.*)?$  /$1.php/$2  last;
    break;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're wrong in assuming that the rewrite string matches GET arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this at all. Just add it to your existing `try_files`:

Example:

```
try_files $uri.php $uri $uri/ @404;
```

If you aren't (yet) using [try_files](http://nginx.org/r/try_files), then [convert soon](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), and in the meantime use something like this:

```
if (-e $request_filename.php) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.php last;
}
```

(I ripped this second example out of my notes from when I originally converted from Apache to nginx and wanted to have a URL `/example` load `/example.php` as Apache would do.)

Comment: I already use try_files, just can't get it working with try_files. Your example just gives me a error 500 page. I have rephrased my question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/410522/need-custom-nginx-regex

Comment: Sorry, I realized after I slept on it that try_files wouldn't work. The second block should have been fine, though. In any case, it's bad form to post duplicate questions; if you need to clarify your question you can just edit the original question.