# Need custom Nginx regex

Tags: nginx, regex

Following is what I have right now and it works but needs some improvement.
I am guessing that I will need to use regex and that is why I need help.

What I need is this

```
http://www.example.com/filename/segment1/segment2/?argk=argv
```

to go to this:

```
http://www.example.com/filename.php/segment1/segment2/?argk=argv
```

Following works without the segments. the index.php works as expected

```
location / {
    try_files $uri  $uri.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php.socket;
}
```

Stuff I tried:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/([^?]*[^?/])/?(\?.*)?$  /$1.php/$2  last;
    break;
}
```

---

```
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/([^./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 last;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `rewrite` directive from the [rewrite module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) along with a regular expression to perform an internal rewrite of the path. Something like this inside the `location /` block should work.

```
rewrite ^/([^./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 last;
```

You'll also need to modify the regular expression of your PHP `location` block to match `.php` files in the middle of the path, so something like this:

```
location ~ \.php(/|$)
```

Comment: Tried this but I get a 404 page  if (!-e $request_filename)
  {
   rewrite ^/([^./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 last;
   break;
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.php$2$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$ {

    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;

    #   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php.socket;
}
```